# How to use a username as page name in php?

Tags: php, url, get

I want to know how you can do: **[www.site.com/username](http://www.site.com/username)** instead of **[www.site.con/username?=myusername.](http://www.site.con/username?=myusername.)**

Are there any reources or techniques to achieve this?

Thanks!

Jules

Comment: Of course there are, it's a very common thing to do. You need to know the terminology to search for though, I guess. [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+friendly+urls)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server you can edit httpd.config file to rewrite URL. Below is a sample rule to rewrite URL.(not an exact solution)

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/(.+)"  "http://example.com/username?usernameVaribale=$1"  [R,L]
```

you can read more about URL rewriting in apache server [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)